# JS Array.push acts in unexpected way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am experiencing unexpected behaviour of push function.
The problem is with the latest line of code cited below.

```
export enum non_searchFieldsNames {
    language = 'language',
    categories = 'categories',
    subtitle = 'subtitle',
    publishedDate = 'publishedDate',
    id = 'id',
}
enum columnsEnum {
    title,
    authors,
    language,
    categories,
    subtitle,
    publishedDate,
}

function toArray(obj: header | contentCategories | sourceFields) {
    return Object.entries(obj)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            return +a - +b;
        })
        .map(item => item[1]);
}

let sourceFieldsObject: sourceFields = {
    [columnsEnum.title]: searchFieldsNames.title,
    [columnsEnum.authors]: searchFieldsNames.authors,
    [columnsEnum.language]: non_searchFieldsNames.language,
    [columnsEnum.categories]: non_searchFieldsNames.categories,
    [columnsEnum.subtitle]: non_searchFieldsNames.subtitle,
    [columnsEnum.publishedDate]: non_searchFieldsNames.publishedDate,
};

const sourceFieldsArray = toArray(sourceFieldsObject).push(non_searchFieldsNames.id);
```

The problem is with the latest line of code. The value I do receive here is 7.
When I simplify it like this

```
const sourceFieldsArray = toArray(sourceFieldsObject)
```

I receive an array(however, without the value I try to add, of course).

When I split the logic

```
const sourceFieldsArray = (toArray(sourceFieldsObject));
sourceFieldsArray.push(non_searchFieldsNames.id);
```

I get what I wanted. Anyway, I would like to have it as one-liner. So, what is my error?
I have tried also

```
const sourceFieldsArray (toArray(sourceFieldsObject)).push(non_searchFieldsNames.id)
```

But it does not help.

Comment: The expression is evaluated left to right, last the function `push` which doesn't return the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) modifies the main array directly, and it does not return a new array as you expected, but the count of items in that array.

You can check the below demo for `push`'s returned value

```js
const array = [1,1,1] //3 items

const count = array.push(1) //1 more item

console.log(count) //total is 4 items
```

If you want to have a one-liner, you can try the cloning approach with [the spreading operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const sourceFieldsArray = [...toArray(sourceFieldsObject), non_searchFieldsNames.id]
```

*Side note that this approach means you're creating a new array completely, so you need to be aware of some performance situations with a huge array.*